# setting up raspberry ubunbu server to connect to wifi on start up

Tags: networking

rpi-imager burns the server image on the SD card and adds a network-config file inside the `system-boot` partition (or whatever this is).

Now, I want to modify it by adding `/etc/netplan/myconfig.yaml` but when issuing `sudo netplan --debug  try` it tells me that the wlan0 SSID is duplicated.

This is because netplan tries to merge my config with the default one, and there is a value that is a duplicate.

Should I remove the `system-boot/network-config` or what is the best procedure here? Can I remove any `system-boot` files from inside the system? I can't find it without plugging the SD card in a different computer.

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server

Comment: @guiverc done thanks